# How to troubleshoot and solve /var/www/html permissions problems?

Tags: linux, command-line, permissions, lamp

So, I am running Debian Stretch with a LAMP server and vsFTPd. When ever I upload a new file or create a new file in the /var/www/html directory with a code editing program, I am unable to view the file/image/what-be-it, until I apply 777 permissions to the /var/www/html folder. I know this is not the best solution but I have ran through several iterations of trying

```
sudo chown $USER:www-data /var/www/mysite
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www
sudo usermod -a -G www-data [my username]
```

and the similar with no luck. How would I go about trouble shooting and eventually solving this issue so I do not need to putty into the server every time I upload some images or a new page to reset permissions.

the www folder has

```
drwxrwsrwx
```

while any subfolder/file created starts with

```
-rw-------
```

Answer (score 0):

After you added `$USER` to the `www-data` group and changed the ownership of the `/var/www/mysite`directory, run the following command:

```
chmod g+s /var/www/mysite
```

The `s` attribute will keep all new files and directories created within the `mysite` directory having the same group ID of the directory, rather than the group ID of the user who created the directory/file.

Comment: I just attempted this and I have the same result 403 Forbidden